# How to create command style functions in pyplot actually work?

Tags: python-2.7, function, matplotlib

I know that pyplot is a package in Python that provides command style functions in Python. For example, consider the following code using python:

```
import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])

plt.ylabel('some numbers')

plt.show()
```

It seemes to me that python is remembering the x-coordinates [1,2,3,4] when we call the first function and print it in some way when we call the last function. However, if I recall correctly, a function does not store any data. So how do python actually remember these informtion? My guess is that the function plt.plot() actually creates some temporary file on our computer hard drive and store information in that file rather than storing the information in some memory location at run time. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a global figure registry which stores the notion of 'current figure' that all of the `pyplot` functions use.  It is definitely all in memory.  If you want to see the details look at `pyplot.py` and `_pylab_helpers.py` is the mpl source.

Comment: @tcaswell It worked, thank you!

Comment: The question is actually pretty good, but disguised with a heavy load of crap.